# disable scroolbar in sap.f.semantic.SemanticPage

Tags: sapui5, scrollbar, semantic-ui, sap-fiori

I want to disable the scroll bar in the semantic page (master) and add a scroll to the list in `semantic:content` only, so my goal is to prevent scroll in the header of the semantic page.

`enableScrolling="false"` doesn't exist in `sap.f.semantic.semantic` page

Comment: you can pin the header, so it doesnt collapse on scroll, wouldnt that do the tric?

Comment: i don't want the scroll bar be shown at all in the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking the API there is no parameter for disabling thescrollbar.
I would try something like this:

- limit content: if `<content>` doesn't exceed the full height, no scrollbar will be visible (try `sap.ui.table.Table` with `visibleRowCount`)
- scroll: add scroll container (`ScrollContainer`) to the content

Example for scroll:

```
<semantic:SemanticPage
    class="noScroll"
    id="mySemanticPage"
    headerPinnable="false"
    toggleHeaderOnTitleClick="false"
    preserveHeaderStateOnScroll="true"
    showFooter="{/showFooter}">

    <!-- Content -->
    <semantic:content>
        <ScrollContainer
                class="myContainer"
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                horizontal="true"
                vertical="true"
                focusable="true">
```

css:

```
.noScroll .sapFDynamicPageContent {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.noScroll .sapFDynamicPageContent > div {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```